# Replacing Resume with Try-Catch in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, try-catch

I have a code block as follow and need to change it to try catch.

```
 Private test(a as String) 
     On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
            Dim index as String 
            Statement1
            Statement2  
    Done:
            On Error Resume Next
            Exit Sub
    ErrorHandler:
            If (a.equals("a")) Then
                Resume
            Else
                Resume Done
            End If
    End Function
```

I looked through the official documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/resume-statement and was able to figure out that this can be written as :

```
Try
    Dim index as String 
    Statement1
    Statement2  
Catch
    If (a.equals("a")) Then 
     Resume (How do we replace this)
    End If
End Try
```

Can someone guide me how do I replace the Resume statement?

Comment: Your code will automatically resume / continue execution after a catch, perhaps for your certain situation you're looking for `Finally`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement

Comment: First of all, this code doesn't compile. Secondly, if you have an exception inside either statement, and "a" was passed, you have an infinite loop. You won't be able to fully replace all this outdated vb stuff (On Error GoTo, Resume) with a try catch. Rethink the logic. Maybe you need to use recursion? It's really unclear what this method should do.

Comment: @Jaxi that's not what no-label `Resume` does in VBA.  Rather, it retries the statement that threw the error---I think it roughly corresponds to the same functionality in SEH.  There is no corresponding capability with `Try`-`Catch`-`Finally`.

Comment: If you really want that behavior, you'll need to build all of the infrastructure yourself: a state variable to keep track of where you are in execution, and a dispatcher to return to the appropriate label based on the contents of the state variable.  You should probably rethink trying to do this generally, though... there aren't a lot of circumstances where it makes sense to retry on an error, and for those where it does make sense, just wrap the `Try`-`Catch` in a loop.